# Is it a sin to be unproductive in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, krishna, karma

I know that doing Karm and hard work is the only source to the fruit.

But does wasting time and not doing Karm is a sin? (wasting time by indulging in materialistic pleasures such as playing video games, partying, social media etc.) Because if we don't do Karm we are basically harming ourselves.

Is it written anywhere that doing anything that does not lead to our ultimate goals is a sin?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: Excess of anything is bad. Ultimate aim is Mokśha, and the other three: Dharma, Arțh, Kâma are the ladders which are to be ultimately given away as one reaches closer to Mokśha.

Comment: Being unproductive is a waste of life. You need not work and you can be absolutely silent but it still is making good use of life because it leads you to your real Self.

Comment: Yes. See Gita Chapter 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unproductiveness is not same as not doing duties. The product of Karma is not in our hands.

Not doing duties--idleness--is not respected. Below are some examples:

Rishi Bharadwaja to Sauviras king Satrunjaya [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a139.htm):

> **They that are idle never win affluence**; nor they that are destitute of manliness and exertion; nor they that are stained by vanity; nor they that fear unpopularity; nor they that are always procrastinating.

Kripaacharya [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10002.htm) to Ashwattama

> **He, on the other hand, that is idle, never obtains happiness**. In this world of men it is generally seen that they that are addicted to action are always inspired by the desire of earning good.

Vidura [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05039.htm) to Dhritarastra:

> One should not place trust on a woman, a swindler, **an idle person**, a coward, one that is fierce, one that boasts of his own power, a thief, an ungrateful person, and an atheist.

Draupadi to Yudhistira urging [him to act](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03032.htm):

> **The idle, however, never achieveth success**. If success, becometh impossible, then should one seek to remove the difficulties that bar his way to success.

Comment: One should not place trust on a woman.Why? Vidura says to Dhritarastra:

Answer (score 1):

According to the Bhagavad Gita (3:6), there is not a moment in life when one can remain without action:

> Karmendriyaani samyamya ya aaste manasaa smaran |
> Indriyaarthaanvimoodhaatmaa mithyaachaarah sa uchyate. ||
>
> > He who, restraining the organs of action, sits thinking of the sense objects in his mind, he, of deluded under-standing, is called a hypocrite.

So prioritize your work and playing video games is not a sin.. Perhaps you are concern on time management.  Because doing more hard and not enjoying life is also not appreciated as what Shebbar mention of Vidur to Dhritrashtra.
One should be balance according to his/her nature.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at:  [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Have an enriching Journey ahead.